# jquery not accepting a quoted variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get a function that changes the "top" and "left" attributes of various div elements to accept an argument where I essentially put quotes around the variable's value.

```
function inQuotes(l) {
    return '"' + l + 'px"';
}

function Rearrange(k, topleft) {
    $(y).css("top", inQuotes(topleft[0])).css("left", inQuotes(topleft[1]));
}
```

where y is a div element with

```
position: absolute
```

positioned in a container div that has

```
position:relative
```

and topleft is an array of 2 values, the top and left number of pixels I want to move the div. However, the script does not run the function when I call it, ignoring it and running the rest of the script.

I have gone through and tested all parts of both functions, and concluded that:

inQuotes(l) returns "lpx" as expected, so inQuotes(40) would return "40px". (Tested by running

```
alert(inQuotes(40));
```

which alerted "40px".)

The jquery selector works; for instance, if y = "#demo", then other jquery methods run as expected.

If z = "40px", then

```
$(y).css("top", z);
```

runs as expected.

This makes me think that inQuotes is not returning a string, but then what is it returning? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You don't need to add quotes at all in that situation.

Answer (score 4):

> This makes me think that inQuotes is not returning a string, but then what is it returning?

It is returning `"lpx"`. (And that is not `"lpx"` as you would write in JS *code* for a text literal, it is a string literally containing `"lpx"`, with the double quotes being part of the *value*.)

Now is that a valid CSS length value? Would you write `top: "1px"` in your stylesheet? No, of course you wouldn’t.

So get rid of the double quotes.

Comment: Lo and behold, it worked! Thank you, kind stranger for helping me out.